# mysql INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES explanation?

Tags: mysql

hello in mysql these are the columns in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES table

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| GRANTEE        | varchar(81)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_CATALOG  | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TABLE_SCHEMA   | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| PRIVILEGE_TYPE | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| IS_GRANTABLE   | varchar(3)   | NO   |     |         |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

so i am wondering what all those columns stands for
i know what the third and fourth column stands for but i don't have any idea what the other columns do coul anyone explain me them  bit? i have been searching on the net but i haven't found anythin only some example values for the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [**MySQL Documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/schema-privileges-table.html), these values are just copied from the mysql.db table. All this does is provide an alternative way to find all users who have been granted a database-level privilege.

### Here is a breakdown of what each column represents

- `GRANTEE` is mysql user that had the privilege granted (`user`@`host` from `mysql.db`)
- `TABLE_CATALOG` is a [**field defined for this table to be SQL-92 compatiple**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3776/877)
- `TABLE_SCHEMA` is the database whose grants are allowed (db column in `mysql.db`)
- `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` is the individual database-level privilege granted in `mysql.db`

  - Select_priv
  - Insert_priv
  - Update_priv
  - Delete_priv
  - Create_priv
  - Drop_priv
  - References_priv
  - Index_priv
  - Alter_priv
  - Create_tmp_table_priv
  - Lock_tables_priv
  - Create_view_priv
  - Show_view_priv
  - Create_routine_priv
  - Event_priv
  - Trigger_priv
- `IS_GRANTABLE` tells you if the user was defined `WITH GRANTS` (Grant_priv column of `mysql.db`) . In other words, the value tells whether or not the mysql user can give away the specific database-level privilege to other mysql users